# Intuition for why repeated sum of digits of a number is concurrent modulo 9?

Tags: intuition

I have come across this question where I have to sum the digits of the number repeatedly until it reduces to single digit, for example `9998` can be reduced to `35` which then it can be reduced to `8`. So, `8` is the answer.

There is correlation between `9998` and `8` as in, `9998 % 9 = 8` ( except when remainder is zero or the number itself is zero ), can someone give me the rough sketch of the proof or intuition?

Thanks much!

Comment: Taking the digit sums preserves the congruence $\pmod 9$ since $10\equiv 1 \pmod 9$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use descriptive titles. "What is this property?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, we have
$$9998 = (999 + 1)\cdot9 + (99 + 1)\cdot9 + (9 + 1)\cdot9 + 8 = 9\cdot(999 + 99 + 9) + 9 + 9 + 9 + 8$$ Adding up $9 + 9 + 9 + 8$, we have
$$9\cdot(999 + 99 + 9) + 35 = 9\cdot(999 + 99 + 9) + (9 + 1)\cdot3 + 5$$ Factoring out the 9 again,
$$9\cdot(999 + 99 + 9 + 3) + 3 + 5$$ Adding up $3 + 5$,
$$9\cdot(999 + 99 + 9 + 3) + 8$$ Hopefully this shows where the digit adding came from.

Comment: Yes! It does exactly that. Thanks a lot.